# How to show a video stored on server on iphone

Tags: iphone, web-services, video-streaming

I have a query regarding showing a video (which is stored on server) on iPhone.

I want show a video in an iPhone Application.
This is not live streaming.

So how the video can be shown?
I have read the Apple's documentation for HTTP streaming of video.

Do I need to call a Web Service?
Is there any tutorial for this?

I have seen the Apple Sample code for MPMoviePlayer.
While the locally stored video works fine, there is problem while showing the video stored on server.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the movie player sample code from the apple  [docs.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007798)

Comment: I have saved videos (in .mp4 and .m4v formats) on a server.
But when I pass the URL to MPMoviePlayer, The player shows the screen with "Loading movie.." for around 15 sec and then comes back to earlier class without showing Video.
There is no error message.

What can be the problem? 
Should the videos on the server be encoded in some format?
What all steps need to be taken on server side?
The Videos on server will be around 1hr long.